# CSS - Positioning Div's

Tags: html, css

I've got three div's I'm working with: **main**, which is a container for the other two, **header** which consists only of an image for now, and **navigation** which has some links. Right now I'm having trouble positioning the navigation div directly under the header div, there's always one line of the main div in between them. Any suggestions on how to go about doing this?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
   <title></title>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="main">

      <div class="header">
         <img src="images/logo.jpg" />
      </div>

      <div class="navigation"><ul id = "linkbar">
         <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Guestbook</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Quotes</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Links</a></li></ul>
      </div>
   </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   background-color: gray;

   margin:0px;
   padding:0px;

}

.header {
   background-color:white;
} 

.main {
   background-color: yellow;
   text-align: center;
   width: 900px;
   margin: auto;
}
   a:link {color:white; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
   a:visited {color:white; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
   a:hover {color:red; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link*/
   a:active {color:red; text-decoration:underline;}  /* selected link */

.navigation {
   text-align: center;
   background-color: f8901f;   
}

#linkbar li {
  margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
  padding: 11px 0px 10px 0px; 
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline;
  line-height: 2.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include following code in your css.

```
ul#linkbar{margin-top:0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a doctype, you are in 'quirks mode'. Add this as your first line and see where we stand: `<!doctype html>`

Comment: Good to know, I've not been declaring a doctype for a while.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Rob, you need to [add a doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) as the very first line such as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

to escape [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Assuming that isn't the only problem, try this:

```
#header img {
    vertical-align: top
}
```

If I understand correctly, that should fix this problem:

> always one line of the main div in
>   between them

Answer (score 0):

I seem to find that the space is caused by the fact that images are inline elements.

try adding:

```
.header img {
    display:block;
}
```

and ofcourse add a valid doctype so you are in standards mode